# method streamDownload returns empty response, file is not downloaded

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I have the following method in my controller, triggered when calling the route '/download/' with POST :

```
public function download(Request $request) {
    return response()->streamDownload( function () use ( $request ) {
        return $request->content;
    }, 'page.html' );
}
```

I'm calling this route via AJAX from my javascript application.

The problem is that the file download does not work. And the response is empty. However, the response code is 200, no error...

What's wrong ?
thanks

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think `file downloads in laravel way` work only with `web calls`, not `ajax calls`, I might be wrong tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I was doing it wrong. Here's my solution :

```
// @param url : the url of the file on server
function downloadHTML (url) {
    url = new URL(url);
    return axios({
        // I've created a GET API route on my server using the pathname of the file url, which returns the content of the file
        url: url.origin + '/api' + url.pathname,
        method: 'GET',
        responseType: 'blob',
    }).then((response) => {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute('download', 'file.pdf'); //or any other extension
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    });
}
```